# Bootstrap modal doesn't appear like popup

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have created a datatable using jquery. Its second column has account numbers. When user will click on account number, then a modal should appear on the page. Something like below image.

[image]

But my modal doesn't appear like popup. It appears like this:
[image]

Below is my code:

```
<div id="select-account-expanded" style="display:none">

        <!-- Begin of select-statement modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="select-statement-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none;">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="select-statement-title">Select Statement(s)</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <table id="statement-table-modal">
                          <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="select-all-statement" value="" /><label for="select-all-statement"></label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>Statement</th>
                                    <th>Due Date</th>
                                    <th>Total Due</th>
                                    <th>Payment Amount</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                       </table>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- End of modal -->
              <table id="multiple-account-table">
                  <thead>
                        <tr class="border-class">
                            <th class="black white-active-bg pad-bottom-0-5">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="select-all-statement" value="" /><label for="select-all-statement"></label>
                            </th>
                            <th>Account Number</th>
                            <th>Account Name</th>
                            <th>Alias</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            <th>Total Due</th>
                            <th>Payment Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td>input type="checkbox" id="statement" value="" /><label for="select-all-statement"></label></td>
                                 <td><span id="launch-modal">1000</span></td>
                                 <td>Alwar</td>
                                 <td>07/07/2015</td>
                                 <td>$1000.00</td>
                                 <td><input type="textbox" value=""/></td>
                              </tr>

                         </tbody>
               </table>
    </div>
```

There is a link, by clicking on that link, modal appears. Below is javascript code for the same:

```
$(document).on('click', '#launch-modal', function () {
    $("#select-statement-modal").modal();
});
```

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**
I found my mistake. There was some mistake in importing bootstrap.min.css file. Now I have corrected.And it started working fine.

Comment: can you please add it in snippet or jsfiddle to see the problem?

Comment: Try `$("#select-statement-modal").modal('show');`

Comment: @RatHat: I did..it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

It Will work properly try to implement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Modals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> -->
               
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="select-statement-title">Select Statement(s)</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
        <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
        <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)"  /></td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)" /></td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)" /></td>
        <td>eee</td>
        <td>fff</td>
    </tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Continue</button>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is a difference between your code and mine.Firstly, I dont have button to launch modal. Actually there is a table in my homepage called "multiple-account-table" (see in the code)
There is a column called account number in that table. When user will click on that account number then modal will launch which will show statements associated with that account. (See in the edited code). This is how I displayed that modal link
 <td><span id="launch-modal">1000</span></td>

Then by help of jquery, I am launching that modal. And modal shows up.. But it doesn't show up like a popup.

Comment: I found my mistake. There was some mistake in importing bootstrap.min.css file. Now I have corrected.And it started working fine.

Comment: ok no problem next time be careful. that code is only for refrence

Answer (score 0):

Having spent a few hours debugging this same problem, I'd like to add a more detailed answer. The problem for me was that I mistakenly loaded the optional bootstrap theme css instead of the core css (on Wordpress):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css',array(),'3.3.7' );
```

I should have loaded this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',array(),'3.3.7' );
```

(see the difference in the URL between the two).